# Where do i save audio file in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, audio

Where should I put audio files, that are used in my project, in my project structure?

Answer (score 1):

`assets/` is usually a good spot for that type of stuff.

Also, [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666934/directory-for-storing-audio-files-in-android) to another question that is similar. This was helpful for me, when i had a similar question.

Comment: Actually res/ won't generally work for audio files, the assets/ directory is the best place for those.

Comment: @Grimmace: lol, oops. Went to fix that typo and then deleted on accident.

Answer (score 1):

I put mine in a folder called raw under res and it works perfectly